# Searching with Hibernate Confusion

Tags: java, hibernate, search, lucene, hibernate-search

I am a beginner to Hibernate. I am browsing many web tutorials which is confusing me. I just want to know the direction which to go with searching when using Hibernate.

Some tutorials are telling use Hibernate Search with Lucene, other saying use criteria while other saying createSQLQuery.

Can someone guide me in this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should start with Hibernate-Core read the [Tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html) and test the examples, modify them. This is IMHO the best way to become familiar with a (any) framework.

Lucene is used by Hibernate-Search which is an extension to Hibernate-Core to index text fields and provide full text search. Don't get confused by the extension unless you managed the core functions.

Comment: Ya, the core function  is OK. When do we mainly use lucene compared to the search service offered by the core

Comment: @Noor Hibernate Search is used when you need an index to perform search operations quickly, e.g. full text retrieval, catalog search in an web-application etc.